# Running java command line from R with system()

Tags: r, shell, selenium, ubuntu, command-line

I need to **run a jar** **file** from **R to shell**. So I write the command line with `system()` on my R script:

```
system("xvfb-run -a java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar")
```

The error seems to be a path problem: *Error: Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar*. This jar file is on */usr/bin/*.

> sessionInfo()
>
> R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
>
> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

What's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try replacing `selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar` with `/usr/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar` ?

Comment: Yes, the output is the same

Comment: That seems…unlikely…if `selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar` really is in `/usr/bin` and the process owner of the running R instance has access to `/usr/bin`.